# how to save the $_POST values of a form to be able to use them later

Tags: php, session

I have created an authentication form that retrieves the user's credentials in a `$_POST` and then passes them as an argument to the `ldap_conn()` and `ldap_bind()` functions to verify their authentication. Once they are identified they are redirected to the home page, here the code:

```
<?php

require_once '../config/config.inc.php';

// Redirection
if (isset($_POST['login'], $_POST['pwd'])){
  
  if ( is_session_started() === FALSE ) session_start();
  session_regenerate_id();

  $_SESSION['SessionId'] = session_id();
  $_SESSION['post-data'] = $_POST;
  
  ldap_connect_auth($host, $port, $login, $pwd, $ldap_base);

  header('location:./home.php');

}
else deny_log();
?>
```

here my config.inc.php:

```
<?php
include_once 'head.php';
require_once 'variable.php';
require_once 'controles.php';

//------------------------------------ Declaration of Functions ------------------------------------//

// Authenticated connection to an LDAP account

function ldap_connect_auth($host, $port, $login, $pwd, $ldap_base) {
    require 'variable.php';
    $ldap_rdn_uid;
    $ldap_pass_uid;
    $port;
    $host;
    $ldap_base;

    // Connect to ldap server
    unset($ldap_conn);
    $ldap_conn = ldap_connect($host, $port) or die("<br/> Unable to connect to the LDAP server. $host : $port </body></html>");

    if ($ldap_conn) {

        $ldap_bind = ldap_bind($ldap_conn, $ldap_rdn_uid, $ldap_pass_uid); 

        // Verify binding
        if ($ldap_bind == 1) {
            echo "<br/> config: LDAP bind ldap successful... $ldap_bind<br>";
        }
        else { ?>  
                <table border="2" style="position:absolute; top:25%; left:35%;">
                <tr>
                    <td align="center">
                    Your connection failed                                                                         <br/><br/>
                        &nbsp;  Please re-enter your username and password. &nbsp; <br/><br/>
                        You must redirect yourself                                                                         <br/><br/>
                        to the <a href="../../login.php">login page</a>.
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <?php
            // DEFINITIVE STOP if bad login
            unset($ldap_conn);
            deny_log();
            exit;
            }
        
        $ldap_filter = ("uid=".$_SESSION['post-data']['login']);

        // Search ldap
        unset($ldap_search);
        $ldap_search = ldap_search($ldap_conn, $ldap_base, $ldap_filter) or die("<br/> No research on $host, ldap base : $ldap_base  ldap filter : $ldap_filter </body></html>");
        $info_ldap = ldap_get_entries($ldap_conn, $ldap_search);

        $number_returned_ldap = ldap_count_entries($ldap_conn, $ldap_search);

        // All attributs ldap
        $entry_ldap = ldap_first_entry($ldap_conn, $ldap_search);
        $attrs_ldap = ldap_get_attributes($ldap_conn, $entry_ldap);
        $dn = ldap_get_dn($ldap_conn, $entry_ldap);
        echo "<br/>" . $attrs_ldap["count"] . " attributs pour : <b>" . $ldap_base . "</b> <br/>";
        echo "<br> dn : " . $dn."&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<br>";
        for ($i=0; $i < $attrs_ldap["count"]; $i++) {
            if ( ( $i == 10 ) || ( $i == 20 ) ) echo "<br/>";
        for ($j=0; $j < $attrs_ldap[$attrs_ldap[$i]]["count"]; $j++)
            echo $attrs_ldap[$i].": ".$attrs_ldap[$attrs_ldap[$i]][$j]. "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<br>";
            }   
    } //end if ($ldap_conn)

  

}
```

The code of head.php:

```
<?php 
if (substr($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], -9) == 'index.php') 
     $dir = 'global/';
else $dir = '..';
?>
<?php 
session_start();
session_regenerate_id();
$_SESSION['SessionId'] = session_id();
// echo $_SESSION['SessionId']."<br>";
?>
```

and my variable.php:

```
<?php

//--- Declaration of Variables ---//


$host = "ldap://my.server.ldap.fr";
$port = "389";

// $login = $_POST['login'];
// $pwd = $_POST['pwd'];

$_SESSION['post-data'] =$_POST;

$ldap_rdn_uid  = 'uid='.$_SESSION['post-data']['login'].',ou=accounts,ou=admin,dc=ufr-mi,dc=u-bordeaux1,dc=fr';
$ldap_pass_uid = $_SESSION['post-data']['pwd'];


// Time Zone
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Paris');

// Base DC
$ldap_base = "dc=ufr-mi,dc=u-bordeaux1,dc=fr";
```

Now, my problem is that I'm trying to create an array,in a page I called navigation.php (accessible from home.php), that will be fed by the result of an LDAP search, the problem is that when I pass the same user credentials as argument, the search fails. While searching for my problem, I noticed that the variables that were supposed to store the $_POST data were empty:

[image: Here is a picture of the print of those variables]

here is the code of navigation.php:

```
<?php
include_once 'head.php';
require_once '../config/config.inc.php';

echo $_SESSION['SessionId'];
echo "<br>";
// echo "<br>".$host;
// echo "<br>".$port;
echo "<br>".$ldap_base;
echo "<br>";
echo "login: ".$_SESSION['post-data']['login'];
echo "<br>";
echo "pwd: ".$_SESSION['post-data']['pwd'];
echo "<br>";
?>

<div class="leftcolumn">
    <div class="card">
    <?php
    labri_connect_auth($host, $port, $_SESSION['post-data']['login'], $_SESSION['post-data']['pwd'], $ldap_base);
    ?>
    </div>

</div>

<?php
    include 'footer.php'
?>
```

Actually I didn't set the array because i want to fix this issue first, that's why there is no array in the code.

So, I tried to use $_SESSION to make the variables reusable later on the same session but it doesn't work or i missed something.

Comment: Session should work, as long as you start your script with `session_start();` everywhere you want to use it. Alternatives are any form of persistent or semi-persistent storage (e.g. file, database, cache, etc)

Comment: You need to start the session, _before_ you try to use it. You got `$_SESSION['post-data'] =$_POST;` in `variable.php`, which in turn gets required by `config.inc.php`, and that one gets required at the beginning of your main script. But you are only calling session_start half a dozen lines below that require statement ...

Comment: Hello,

yes indeed, I forgot to specify that I call a file called head.php, in which I start a session then I call this file when I need it. I modified my post so that you can see its code.

Comment: Please be consistent with variables throughout the entire question. `$POST != $_POST != $_post`

Answer (score 1):

So to answer all your opinions, yes I have checked that I have executed `session_start()` every time I need it.

When I run an echo of the session ID. I have the same ID on every page.

My problem is actually on the side of saving the values of `$_POST`.

I managed to solve my problem by replacing `$_SESSION['post-data'] = $_POST;`
with

```
  $_SESSION['login'] = $_POST['login'];
  $_SESSION['pwd'] = $_POST['pwd'];
```

A classic "back to basics" solution. I don't quite understand why one works and the other doesn't, maybe creating a variable that is an array of an array ...?